# How to get the requested data using Angular.js $http service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I need one help.I need to retrieve the data present in body part of a URL using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
var app=angular.module('hello',[]);
app.controller('Hello',function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://oditek.in/medilink_global_new/#/product/Api/apiCatagory').
        success(function(data) {
            console.log('data',data);
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
});
```

In console message i need the required json data.

The controller function of `http://oditek.in/medilink_global_new/#/product/Api/apiCatagory` is given below.

```
var cat=angular.module('medilink');
cat.controller('apiCatagoryController',function($state,$http,$scope){
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/category.php?op=disp",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        //console.log('catagory',response.data);
        $scope.catadata=response.data;
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    });
})
```

> catagory.html:

```
<div>
{{catadata}}
</div>
```

> route.js:

```
.state('api',{
        url:'/Api',
        templateUrl:'Apiview/api.html',
        controller:'apiController'
    })
.state('api.catagory',{
        url:'/apiCatagory',
        templateUrl:'Apiview/catagory.html',
        controller:'apiCatagoryController'
    })
```

> index.html:

```
<div  ui-view>

</div>
```

Here inside body part i am displaying the (`$scope.catadata`) DB values.I need when any user will call this URL to get the data the data will deliver to the user.Please help me.

Comment: So what's your problem here? What are you getting in `//console.log('catagory',response.data);`?

Comment: @Fissio : Here i am getting the required data for this(`medilink`) app.When i am using this app url in other app like `hello`,i need these data there.Check my post again.I am explaining two app at a time and here i am using `ui-router`.

Comment: In the second example you call a different URL, so how is that going to work?

Comment: @JohannesJander : In second example i am storing the db values to `$scope.catadata`. In another application i am requesting the second example URL to get those db values.